# Processing / Cannot refer to the non final local variavle I definied in an enclosing scope

Tags: java, class, unit-testing, for-loop, processing

I'm new to processing/Java and I try to make a little game ...
I already created a class for making something like a map or a layout, I called it Map Class, it worked fine and I could use arrays/ images or just objects to create a "Map".
So now I want to add some units into my game. They shouldn't be so difficult or complex. I just want to move them, heres my class for units :

```
class Unit
{

int X;
int Y;
int Breite;
int Laenge;
boolean ausgewaelht = false;

Unit()
{



}

Unit(int x, int y, int breite, int laenge)
{



}
```

/-------------------------------------------------------------------

```
void create(UnitContent function)
{


  function.form();


}

void move(float geschwindigkeit)
{

  if(isTriggerd(X,Y,Breite,Laenge) == true){

  X = X+(int)geschwindigkeit;

  if(X > width)
  {

    X = 0;

  }
  }

}  

void setXandY(int x , int y)
 {

   X = x;
   Y = y;


 } 

 void setBreiteandLaenge(int breite, int laenge)
 {

   Breite = breite;
   Laenge = laenge;

 }
```

/--------------------------------------------------------------------

```
 int getX()
 {

return X;

 }

 int getY()
 {

  return Y;

 } 

 int getBreite()
 {

  return Breite;

 }

 int getLaenge()
 {

   return Laenge;

 }
```

/--------------------------------------------------------------------

```
 boolean isTriggerd(int x, int y, int breite, int laenge)
  {

    if(mouseX > x && mouseX < x+breite && mouseY > y && mouseY < y+laenge )
    {

      return true;

    }
    else 
    {

      return false; 

    }

 }

 }
```

If I only use 1 Unit it works fine ^ I can personally select outside the class in what kind of form my unit draws on the screen... But how do I draw 10 of them?

Heres my interface UnitContent:

```
interface UnitContent
{

   void form();

}
```

And heres my MainClass

```
Map testKarte;
Unit[] TestEinheit = new Unit[100];

int[][] array = {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
             {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
             {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
             {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
             {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
             {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
             {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
             {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
             {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};

int a = 0;


void setup()
 {

 size(500,500);


 testKarte = new Map(1,1,"",50,50);

 for(int i = 0; i < TestEinheit.length; i++)
 {

   TestEinheit[i] = new Unit();
   TestEinheit[i].setXandY(0,0);
   TestEinheit[i].setBreiteandLaenge(50,50);

 }



 }




  void draw()
  {

    background(#FFFFFF);   

   testKarte.setCisClickable(true);
  testKarte.setIsRectOrPicture(true);
  testKarte.ubdate(new MapContent(){
             public void setMapContent(int a, int b, int c, int d){



               // rect(a,b,c,d);  

               for( int i = 0; i < TestEinheit.length; i++)
                  {                                                             
                    TestEinheit[i].create(new UnitContent()
                  {

                         public void form()
                         {

                                   rect(TestEinheit[i].getX(),TestEinheit[i].getY(),TestEinheit[i].getBreite(),TestEinheit[i].getLaenge());


                         }


              });
            }
            }



             public void setMapContentMouseOver(){





             }
            public void elseMapContentMouseOver()
            {

              // wenn die Maus nicht über dem Object ist
              // ebenfalls nicht unbedingt




            }});






   }

  void mousePressed()
{



}
```

When I try following :

```
 for( int i = 0; i < TestEinheit.length; i++)
               {                                                             
                  TestEinheit[i].create(new UnitContent()
                  {

                    public void form()
                     {


                                    rect(TestEinheit[i].getX(),TestEinheit[i].getY(),TestEinheit[i].getBreite(),TestEinheit[i].getLaenge());


                     }


                  });
```

It gives me following error: Cannot refer to the non final local variavle I definied in an enclosing scope
By the way, the public void form is just an interface method :)

Anyone got an idea how to handle this ?

Comment: The error message is fairly clear and specific. What part of it are you having trouble with? Local classes cannot refer to non-`final` local variables. So you won't be able to use `i` in your `UnitContent`.

Comment: Yeah thats true.... but im searching a way to handle that... how can i do that without that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> im searching a way to handle that... how can i do that without that error?

You have a couple of options, depending on what you want the `form` method to see

- The value of `i` as it is when the `UnitContent` is *created*, or
- The value of `i` as it is when `UnitContent#form` is called **later**

#### The value of `i` when `UnitContent` is *created*

You'll need a subclass of `UnitContent` that accepts `i` as an argument in the constructor, stores it on a field, and uses it in `form`.

E.g.:

```
abstract class MyUnitContent extends UnitContent {
    protected int i;

    public MyUnitContent(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

and

```
TestEinheit[i].create(new MyUnitContent(i) {
    public void form() {
        Unit entry = TestEinheit[this.i];
        rect(entry.getX(), entry.getY(), entry.getBreite(), entry.getLaenge());
    }
});
```

(Note that if `TestEinheit` is a local, it must be `final`.)

#### The value of `i` when `UnitContent#form` is called **later**

The restriction is you can only access `final` **variables**; it doesn't necessarily follow that those variables can't refer to objects with mutable state.

So you could make `i` an array, for instance:

```
final int[] i = new int[1];
for (i[0] = 0; i[0] < TestEinheit.length; i[0]++) {
    TestEinheit[i].create(new UnitContent() {
        public void form() {
            Unit entry = TestEinheit[i[0]];
            rect(entry.getX(), entry.getY(), entry.getBreite(), entry.getLaenge());
        }
    });
}
```

Now, when `form` is called, it will read the value `i[0]` has when it's called (in the code above, it'll be `TestEinheit.length` for all of them).

(Note that if `TestEinheit` is a local, it must also be `final`.)

Comment: thx for your help :) but it wont work either ... so many exceptions ... just added my "Main class" and the UnitContent Interface :/

Comment: @genar: The above definitely addresses the question you asked. That doesn't mean your code will be free from *other* issues.